# Magento 2 set-dimensions-mode gives error

Tags: magento2, reindex

Iam trying to do reindexing-in-parallel-mode and I am trying to change the dimensions mode according to the document

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#reindexing-in-parallel-mode

I am getting this error

```
bin/magento indexer:set-dimensions-mode catalog_product_price website

"Product Price" indexer process unknown error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'db.catalog_product_index_price_cg0_ws1' doesn't exist,
```

Any idea how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the dimensions mode via the CLI, Magento should create the needed tables (See `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price::createTables($currentMode)`)

If however, this particular part fails, or more likely you've switched the dimensions mode some other way, e.g. via a datapatch, this method is never called, leading to the errors we see here.

To get around this, we can just call this method ourselves via a datapatch:

```
Class CreateDimensionsTables implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private ModeSwitcher $modeSwitcher;

    public function __construct(ModeSwitcher $modeSwitcher)
    {
        $this->modeSwitcher = $modeSwitcher;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->modeSwitcher->createTables(DimensionModeConfiguration::DIMENSION_WEBSITE_AND_CUSTOMER_GROUP);
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
       return [SetPriceIndexerDimensionsMode::class];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

This should create any needed tables and the indexer should be able to run successfully.

Comment: That error suggests it's looking for customer group as well as website, so I'm not sure if you previously tried to set it to that. Might be worth trying bin/magento indexer:set-dimensions-mode website_and_customer_group and then bin/magento indexer:set-dimensions-mode catalog_product_price website